# Does javascript have a range function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi all i was just wondering if JS has a range function which will return numbers defined in an offset. I'm not using jQuery, so pure JS would be the best solution for me.

I want to get a set of numbers in sets of 5 i.e.

1. First set of numbers - 0 - 4
2. Second set of numbers - 5 - 10
3. Third set of numbers - 11 - 16
4. And so on and so on

I was wondering if this is possible at all? I was also looking at the underscore library to see if there's any handy methods but i couldn't find anything related to this at all.

Comment: They're sets of 6. What format do you want the results? As arrays, or...? Is a "range" of 6-11 going to be [6, 11], or [6,7,8,9,10,11], or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn I've corrected the values thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35530319/5583289) solve your problem? Anything missing? :)

Comment: _"if JS has a range function which will return numbers defined in an offset"_ What is an "offset" ? Are numbers stored in an array ? Or is requirement to generated numbers between a range , then return the generated numbers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `underscore.js` function `_.range()`:

```
_.range(10);
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
_.range(1, 11);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
_.range(0, 30, 5);
//=> [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
_.range(0, -10, -1);
//=> [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
_.range(0);
// => []
```

See more [here](http://underscorejs.org/#range).

**UPDATE**

If you are using ES6, this is a native method of filling an array:

```
Array(range).fill().map((x,i)=>i);
```

For older versions of JavaScript, you could just create a for loop and add the values manually.

Comment: this solution requires using underscore

Answer (score 7):

If you're using ES6/2015 then you can also do this in pure JS (although, a little messy :P)

```
Array(5).fill().map((x,i)=>i);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to pull in the entire underscore.js library if this is the only function you need.

I'm assuming you're working with an array data structure. There is no `range` function in JavaScript but there are native array functions that you can use to get the same results.

I recommend using the `slice` method. For example, given the following:

`var list = [1, 34, 5, 8, 13]`

If we want the first three numbers (range of 0-2) , we can do:

`list.slice(0,3)`

The first argument to slice represents the index of the first number you want to include and the second argument is the ending index you want your range to include up to (but not including). This is a bit confusing and requires that you calculate and store the correct index values, so we should make up our own procedural abstraction.

We can write our own `range` function since that's really the proper abstraction in this context. Lets say that the first argument is the index you want to start at and the second argument is the size of the set.

```
var range = function (list, beginIndex, size) {
    return list.slice(beginIndex, beginIndex + size);
}
```

Using this function, we can get a set of numbers from any list. Using the example above using the concepts of a list, the starting index of the set, and the size of the set.

To get a set of 7 beginning form an index of 12:

`range(list, 12, 7);`